# How to wait for an Observable within switchMap?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an array of model objects.
These model objects need to be transformed.
Within the transform, I want to wait for another Observable.

How do I achieve this with Observables?
Here is my current code:

```
private createButtons(buttons: ButtonV4[]): Observable<Entity> {
    return from(buttons).pipe(
        switchMap((b: ButtonV4) => {
            const button: Entity = document.createElement("a-image");
            const url: string = this.dataProvider.buildURL(b.image);

            this.textureService.loadTexture(url).subscribe((blob: Texture)  => { 
                button.setAttribute("material","src",`url(${blob.dataUrl})`);
            });
            
            button.setAttribute("position",new THREE.Vector3(b.x,b.y,b.z));
            button.setAttribute("rotation",new THREE.Vector3(0,0,b.rotation));
            button.setAttribute("width",b.width/5);
            button.setAttribute("height",b.height/5);
            return of(button); // Wait for texture before returning of(button);
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need this:

```
private createButtons(buttons: ButtonV4[]): Observable<Entity> {
  return from(buttons).pipe(
    map((b: ButtonV4) => ({ url: this.dataProvider.buildURL(b.image), b })),
    switchMap(({ url, b }: { url: string; b: ButtonV4 } => this.textureService.loadTexture(url)
      .pipe(
        map((blob: Texture) => {
          const button: HTMLElement = document.createElement("a-image");
          button.setAttribute("material","src",`url(${blob.dataUrl})`);
          button.setAttribute("position",new THREE.Vector3(b.x,b.y,b.z));
          button.setAttribute("rotation",new THREE.Vector3(0,0,b.rotation));
          button.setAttribute("width",b.width/5);
          button.setAttribute("height",b.height/5);
          return button;
        }),
        map((button: HTMLElement): Entity => {
          // Here transform button to Entity type and return it.
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: dang! you beat me to it!  Yes, don't `subscribe`, but rather pipe the `loadTexture()` result.  Then, the `map()` operator has access to all the values it needs to create the buttton (`b`, `blob`).  The of course it's not necessary to use `of` .

Comment: Thank you.
I get the following error though:
`rgument of type '(b: ButtonV4) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ButtonV4, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.`

Comment: What type does return the function `this.textureService.loadTexture(url)`?

Comment: I got it now :)